# Yii2 picking up the wrong route on modal

Tags: modal-dialog, yii2

Something changed between Yii 2.0.3 and 2.0.4 that is breaking my application.

If I have a form open and, within that form, I pop open a modal (with its own post action), the route that fires is the one for the open form, not the modal.

The simplest example is an update form that includes a grid with a delete action on each line item.  After prompting for the delete confirmation, the route that fires is the form's update, not the grid's line item delete.

Any ideas?  Do I have to move back to 2.0.3?  Mahalo.

Best,
Joe

Comment: Look a the changelog? Add some code? It's not as if you're giving us much to go on.

Comment: @Blizz: Yes, I looked at the changelog and no, the code has not changed.  It had been working before I moved up to 2.0.4.  I did see an issue which looks close to what I am experiencing: [link] (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8236) but the workaround of removing client side validation did not work for me.